# mathematics around ranking

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, algorithms, oc.optimization-and-control

> Is there interesting mathematics around ranking? (I mean ranking as reputation points here at mathoverflow.)

It looks obvious that *there is no way to make adequate ranking* --- is it a theorem, at least if the ranking is a function on the set of users?

On the other hand, one may imagine that ranking is a function of pairs of users, and it might take values in something more complicated. In this case there might be rig-proof ranking, but is it even defined?

---

This post was misunderstood by almost everyone, so let me try to clarify:

On one hand, a straightforward attempt to define ranking brings Arrow's theorem into the game that says --- it is impossible --- there is nothing better than dictatorship.
On the other hand, let us take MO as an example, you want to rank users according to *your own* rule and use it to decide if a post worth investing *your* time.
In this case, rank is a function on the edges of complete oriented graph on all users.
But there is another problem --- a user cannot have a sufficient number of interactions to make such a decision --- so either you do not read most of the posts or read too many.
We may take into account the ranking of users that have a good rank in your system.
One possibility is that instead of a number you get a maximal subgraph formed by disjoint paths from A (you) to B (another user).

What is described is just one possible attempt. Was something like this used somewhere? Did you see other constructions that is impossible to fake?

Another request: please do not bring PageRank here again --- it can be faked easily (assuming you have enuf resources).

Comment: PageRank is maybe one keyword here...

Comment: @Sam I do not think PageRank is related to my question.

Comment: Something around Arrow's Impossibility Theorem?

Comment: @auniket maybe, but does not seem to be directly relevant. At least if you want relativistic ranking (= function of odered pair of users).

Comment: Another possibly related measure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index

Comment: @SamHopkins I am interested in mathematical aspects of ranking and H-index is not about it.

Comment: *rank aggregation problem* or *minimum feedback arc set*

Comment: One more try, then: there is the Kendall-Wei method for ranking the elements of a tournament (result of a head-to-head competition between $n$ vertices), which you can read about for instance in this short note http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~reiner/Classes/Tournaments.pdf.

Comment: @SamHopkins all this close, but not exactly on the subject. Ranking (as I see it) is not about finding winner, it should give an idea about user you do not know, and most likely you do not care what majority think about him...

Comment: @AntonPetrunin That may be because the problem itself doesn't give much to go on. The first question - "Is there interesting mathematics around ranking? " - might be worth exploring (though I expect that it's more psychology than math), but the rest looks to me like underdefined statements with very little that can be answered. What do you think "adequate" means? Or "rig-proof"?

Comment: @user44191 so you try to say that the answer is "no" --- there is no meanful mathematical statemens around this topic --- possibly you are right.

Comment: Are you asking about what mathematical ways there are to rank things/people? In that case you might be interested in the Elo system (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) which is highly mathematical

Comment: @MiloMoses, it uses mathematics, but is there a theorem about this system?

Comment: Search for scoring rules. The literature is huge.

Comment: I've read your revision (May 4th) but I do not understand what the goal of a ranking might be.  What is a ranking, and what would it represent?

Comment: @RyanBudney maybe it is better to say "reputation", ranking is indeed a misleading term. Can it be measured, can it be defined, and so on.

Comment: Hi Anton, it's still unclear to me what exactly you want to measure or define.  It sounds like you have some sort of implied definition, using extrapolation from common-usage English language.  I imagine most people want more to go on than that.  Reputation in the MO sense is a fairly concrete (albeit, sometimes changing) algorithm.   Reputation in an idealized English-language sense is purely subjective.  Someone who is very reputable to me might mean nothing to someone else, or the reverse. This is sort of like university rankings.  They're all different, and any one is likely justifiable.

Comment: @RyanBudney that is why it should be a function on ordered pairs.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin And what is it you want out of this function? Any specific properties? Any ways rankings should be interrelated? Right now, the only mathematical property you've specified is "it's a function of ordered pairs", which...well, it's vague enough that sure, there are certainly interesting things, but they're mostly not focused on being functions of ordered pairs. So what mathematical structure are you thinking about *beyond* being a function on ordered pairs?

Comment: @user44191 It is okay to say that it measures what it measures; the point is that it cannot be faked --- one cannot change the value by organizing activity that you (and your friends) do not see.

Answer (score 4):

There is a relatively recent book [The science of rating and ranking](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2894870) by Langville and Meyer which provides a reasonable survey.

Comment: It seems that the title of my questions, moves everybody in wrong direction. (I have a feeling that no one has read the question carefully.)

Comment: Right. If everyone misunderstands the question, it must be because everyone is careless. It couldn't possibly be because the question is poorly worded.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, sure the is poorly worded, maybe now I would do it better, but I could not imagine so many misunderstands.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of interesting mathematics related to ranking. See, for example this paper which explains how Google ranks web pages using Singular Value decomposition:
[T. Moh, 25 billion dollar eigenvector](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/dvi/google.pdf). When you mention "impossibility of ranking", you probably mean [Arrow's theorem](https://blogs.ams.org/mathgradblog/2016/11/21/mathematical-democracy-mission-impossible-not/). But there are multiple mathematical formulations of "ranking problems".

Comment: Indeed, Arrow's theorem might be inteprited as "there is no adequate ranking as a function of user". But is there any research on other types of ranking?

Comment: @Anton Petrunin: sure, I gave you one reference, and the other answer contains another one. Look also under "order statistics".

Comment: By the way, about google ranking --- it use mathematics, but there are no meanigful mathematical statements about it; or am I wrong?

Comment: @Anton Petrunin Mathematically it is based on the existence of a stationary distribution for a finite Markov chain. Finding it explicitly for a large state space is a non-trivial problem from numerical analysis.